# In Chrome, do iframes consume resources in the same way as tabs?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium

I need to cycle automatically through several webpages using Chrome. There are Chrome extensions which will cycle tabs like this, but I wonder if iframes and setInterval could work too.

I want to keep each page open once I've loaded it, i.e. I would need to make many iframes and show/hide them, rather than reload on each change by setting the src on a single iframe.

Bearing in mind that the end result needs to be run for long periods of time, are there significant advantages or disadvantages to using multiple iframes instead of tabs?

Comment: I think Chrome loads each tab in a different process. That has some memory costs, which you probably won't have with iframes in the same tab.

Comment: Hey @oriol, thanks! I'm concerned Chrome looks after tabs a bit more carefully, e.g. If they develop memory leaks?

Comment: That's probably part of the process model. The main difference I can see is if Javascript blocks in an iframe, it blocks that whole tab. And if there's a Javascript fatal error (like an infinite loop) it will kill the whole tab.